# How do I change the page language in Next.js App Router programmatically

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am localising a website in Next.js 13 using App Router.

Most of the routes are behind `[lang]` and the process there seems straightforward. But there a few routes in which the language is defined in the database and the existing links look like `/post/ABCD123`. I want to keep these intact and only set the correct language using `<html lang="">` The language (and other meta data) is only available after the document is fetched from the database.

Next.js docs mention this code for the root layout static generation:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'en-US' }, { lang: 'de' }]
}
 
export default function Root({ children, params }) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This is exactly what I want - But how do I set the lang param from inside a route which is not behing `[lang]` path? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself - this is probably impossible. As per Next.js docs, there is no way to pass anything between the RootLayout and components as well as the underlying path parameters are not visible to RootLayout.

The only way to achieve this that I found is to actually move everything behind [lang] path (including the RootLayout).